# Why does CNN with constant initialization learn at all?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, mnist

Usually, weights for neural networks are initialized randomly so that they receive different gradients and learn different weights. In theory, if all weights are initialized the same way, all nodes will have the same weights no matter how long you train. Thus the training shouldn't work at all.

However, the code below gives 56% accuracy on MNIST after 7000 epochs. Why is that the case?

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""MNIST with Tensorflow."""

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

import os
import numpy as np

epochs = 20000
model_checkpoint_path = 'checkpoints/mnist_tf_model.ckpt'


def weight_variable(shape):
    #initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.01)
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape=shape)
    return tf.get_variable(initializer=initial, name='weights')


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.get_variable(initializer=initial, name='biases')


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                          strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def eval_network(sess, summary_writer, dataset, correct_prediction, epoch):
    correct_sum = 0
    total_test = 0
    training_summary = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("training_accuracy:0")
    loss_summary = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("loss:0")
    for i in range(dataset.labels.shape[0] / 1000):
        feed_dict = {x: dataset.images[i * 1000:(i + 1) * 1000],
                     y_: dataset.labels[i * 1000:(i + 1) * 1000]}

        [test_correct, train_summ, loss_summ] = sess.run([correct_prediction,
                                                          training_summary,
                                                          loss_summary],
                                                         feed_dict=feed_dict)
        summary_writer.add_summary(train_summ, epoch)
        summary_writer.add_summary(loss_summ, epoch)
        test_correct = correct_prediction.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
        correct_sum += sum(test_correct)
        total_test += len(test_correct)
    return float(correct_sum) / total_test


def log_score(sess, summary_writer, filename, mnist, scoring, epoch):
    with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
        train = eval_network(sess, summary_writer, mnist.train, scoring, epoch)
        test = eval_network(sess, summary_writer, mnist.test, scoring, epoch)
        myfile.write("%i;%0.6f;%0.6f\n" % (epoch, train, test))


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1, name='ReLU1')
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
        W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2, name='ReLU2')
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    with tf.variable_scope('fc1'):
        W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

        h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
        W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

        y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv * 10**-7),
                                                  reduction_indices=[1]))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.scalar_summary("training_accuracy", accuracy, name="training_accuracy")
    tf.scalar_summary("loss", cross_entropy, name="loss")

    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('summary_dir', sess.graph)

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in range(epochs):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            log_score(sess, summary_writer,
                      'validation-curve-accuracy.csv',
                      mnist, correct_prediction, i)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0],
                                  y_: batch[1]})

    log_score(sess, summary_writer, 'validation-curve-accuracy.csv',
              mnist, correct_prediction, epochs)
```

### Plots

#### Nr 1

After adding `10**-7` to the `tf.log(..)` term, the NANs are gone:

[image]

[image]

#### Nr 2

This is an old plot which did have a problem due to `log(0)` after 16k epochs.

The loss is plotted here. The triangles are NANs.

[image]

Here is the accuracy - due to the smoothing, it does not directly fall to ~10%.

[image]

Comment: Add a small epsilon to `tf.log`, one of possible solutions for `NaN` problem

Comment: @Kh40tiK Thank you. I fixed it :-)

Comment: Can you fetch the actual values of the convolution kernels to verify they have exactly similar weights?

Comment: Your intuition is correct in case of standard (mini batch) gradient descent. You're using adam, that's adaptive. Try to repace adam with GradientDescentOptimizer and you're intuition will be verified.

Comment: You have to 'break the symmetry'.  See the results when layer size = 1.